# App is not compatible with the device (iPad 3 and 4), when installing from app bundle

Tags: ios, compatibility

OK, I have spent couple weeks on this, read pretty much all posts on this topic, and even resubmit a build to the app store but still cannot fix this problem. Please help.

There are 2 apps in the app bundle, if I look at each app on the App Store, both of them have the Compatibility info saying "Requires iOS 8.0 or later. Compatible with iPhone, iPad and iPod touch" like this:

[image]

But looking at the app bundle, it says:

[image]

iPad 3 and 4 are not included in the list, and several (not many) users reported that when they install the app bundle on their iPad 3, it says "App is not compatible with the device".

The build of the 2 apps has the following device requirement
[image]

I don't really understand what went wrong, I think my apps support both 32bit and 64bit devices, but why the app bundle is not compatible with the old iPad 3/4?

Comment: Apple now supports only 64-bit architecture.please check this [link](https://apple.slashdot.org/story/17/02/01/1215200/the-future-of-ios-is-64-bit-only----apple-to-stop-support-for-32-bit-apps)

Comment: by screen shot it is clear that arm64 is supported. @Virender

Comment: @Virender, yeah I know 32bit is coming to an end on iOS 10.3.x, but the iPad 3 in question has iOS 9.x installed.

Answer (score 2):

your required capabilities in your `info.plist` should be `armv7`. Make sure it's value!

[image]

Comment: I don't think that by adding armv7 in `info.plist` will make it support for ipad 3 and 4. by screen shot, it is been clearly shown that armv7 and arm64 has been supported there. It must be different for not showing those devices.

Comment: It does not make sense to me, to specifically require device has armv7 capacity when armv7 has been supported.